# BASH List header of empty sqlite database

Tags: database, bash, sqlite

I'm currently using the following command in bash to list the info from an sqlite3 database

```
sqlite3 -header /path/to/database.db "select * from TABLEHERE";
```

However the issue is that if the database is empty it comes back as null and doesn't list the headers. How can i list the headers of an empty table in bash? I also need it in one command as it will be run in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know anything about the plain header, but you can get the tableinfo by using the `table_info` pragma.

```
sqlite3 your.db "pragma table_info(your_table)"
```

Comment: just changed your command to sqlite3 but it outputted the headers of the empty database and i was able to substring it easily in java thanks for the help!